# How to check if logged in user has a particular role in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Here is my code:

```
$user = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
if($user->has['dce']){
    echo true;
}
else
{
    echo false;
}
```

This is what I get:

> Call to a member function has() on integer

Comment: Because $user is integer. You asked for id of user, so you get his id, not user object.

Comment: what stupid I am!!! thanks big time dude

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`can()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#can()-detail) method:

```
return Yii::$app->user->can('dce');
```

You can find more info in documentation in [Access Check](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#access-check) section.

Answer (score 0):

in rbac

create some Roles

```
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
    $auth->removeAll();

    $operator = $auth->createRole('operator');
    $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');

    $auth->add($operator);
    $auth->add($admin);

    $auth->addChild($admin, $operator);
```

add permission

```
    $someaction = $auth->createPermission('someaction');
    $someaction->description = 'ome action';
    $auth->add($someaction);
```

and

```
    $auth->addChild($admin, $someaction);
```

now

```
if(Yii::$app->user->can('someaction')){
    return true;
} else{
   return false;
}
```